# how to avoid ternary for undefined and boolean check?

Tags: javascript

From this,

`{[item.name]: item.value !== undefined ? item.value : ''}`

when value is,,, it must be

```
false -> {[item.name]: false}
true -> {[item.name]: true}
'str' -> {[item.name]: 'str'}
undefined -> {[item.name]: ''}
```

How do I avoid the ternary operator?

```
item.value !== undefined ? item.value : ''
```

`item.value | ''` fails because when value is `false`, it sets `''` instead.

Comment: You need to explain your problem. Just copying bits of your code doesn't help anyone to help you. Formulate your question, what are you trying to do, what is happening, what should happen and why is it not happening. What have you tried to solve your issues and what did not work. Else, it's difficult to comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For modern browsers (*not IE*) there exist the [Nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) `??` which returns the right-hand side only when the left-hand is `null` or `undefined`.

So you can do

```
{[item.name]: item.value ?? ''}
```